# Rails: Trying to update an attribute on a join table | getting TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments_users, class_name: "AssignmentsUsers"
  has_many :assignees, through: :assignments_users, source: :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments_users, class_name: "AssignmentsUsers"
  has_many :assignments, through: :assignments_users, source: :assignment

class AssignmentsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == Schema Information
  #  completed_on :datetime
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assignment
end


$ @assignment.assignments_users.first.update(completed_on: Time.now)
> TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string
```

I know this is due to the join table not having a primary key. 
That is intentional per most tuts.

So if a join table is not meant to have a primary key, how does one update an attribute on it?

Comment: What does `@assignment.assignments_users.first` return?

Comment: You have the association `has_many :assignments_users` with model name `AssignmentsUsers` (and not `AssignmentsUser`, singular). Do you have a reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the join table is not mean to have a primary key when you're using HABTM.

Since you're storing data on the join table you are, appropriately, using `has_many :through`. In this case, you should use a proper table (including `id`) for the join table.

BTW, I would think your join model might be `UserAssignment` with the table being `user_assignments` which, IMO, reads a little more naturally. In which case, you would do:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_assignments
  has_many :assignees, through: :user_assignments, source: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_assignments
  has_many :assignments, through: :user_assignments
end

class UserAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # == Schema Information
  #  completed_on :datetime
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assignment
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> So if a join table is not meant to have a primary key, how does one update an attribute on it?

Premise invalid; it *is* meant to have a primary key, and that's how one updates an attribute on it.

While a table for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association does not need a primary key, if you're using a first class `ActiveRecord::Base` instance, it does. (You *might* get away without it for a limited set of operations, which could possibly be enough to treat it like a simple join, but as you've seen, that can only get you so far.)

I can't speak to "most tuts", but [the Active Record Associations guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) certainly shows an `id` attribute on `appointments`.